# Google Chrome opens a blank page when searching from Chrome Omnibox / address bar

Tags: google-chrome

When I enter a search criteria in the Omnibox, Chrome seems to offer me a blank page instead of completing the search & offering the results.

Note that if I opt for a Google Instant/Omnibox suggestion, it works fine

[image]

---

However, I choose to ignore the suggestion and try to do a Google search, I get a blank page.

[image]

---

[image]

What can I do make the Omnibox search complete successfully?

Comment: You are not the only one http://superuser.com/a/444251/71027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing cache doesn't work.

To solve this problem, disable instant search. This is a widespread issue occurring today, and it appears that is the fix.

It worked for me, I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed it for *me*:

**1. Cleared my cache and cookies for the last week.**

Went to: `chrome://chrome/settings/` At the bottom of the page you'll see 'Show Advanced Settings' and Clear Browsing data...

**2. Deleted Google Drive Extension**

Open a new tab, right click on Google Drive Icon and Delete Extension

**3. Turned instant search ON (it was originally turned off in my computer)**

I suppose turning it off and on again would do the trick...

**4. Restarted Browser**

The problem is fixed and the omnibar search has been working fine for the last hour. Both instant search ON and OFF work for me...

Cheers

Comment: Ok this is weird, the problem is back, but the weirdest thing is that everything works fine if you enter incognito mode...

Comment: no, clear browsing data didn't make any difference for me.

Comment: @Sathya: Did you restart your browser? Like I commented before being downvoted "The problem is back..." but after I restarted it's working again...

Comment: @Sathya Some users are reporting that just enabling and disabling extensions work for them...

Comment: for me it was the turn off/on instant which seemed to have worked - thanks for editing in your answer with some possible options

Answer (score 1):

I disabled instant search from Google.com's search settings option, which BTW, does not appear till you first search something (or maybe I can't find it). This solved it. However, enabling Instant Search again seems to keep the problem away and I am no longer facing it.

Answer (score -1):

Wow all that extra stuff. All you need to do:

Add a new a search engine in wrench >> settings >> search “Manage Search Engines”.

Under “other search engines” add a new search engine using this address for the URL:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=%s
```

Name it “Google 2″ or whatever you want. Works like a charm.

Comment: Chrome team member and Omnibox owner has mentioned you should *not* do this http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4192779

Comment: Well, they should publish a fix that works, then. My GFs laptop still does this randomly. I've tried everything. Reinstalling Chrome, disabling/uninstalling all extensions, deleting history (can't keep doing that...), plus a whole lot more. This workaround is the only thing that works consistently.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is go to setting-searchengine and select google and change .com to your country. In my case changing it to NL solved to issue.